# A text or book in holomorphic foliations and vector fields over complex manifolds

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, dynamical-systems, complex-geometry

For my master's degree dissertation, I am going to study some implications of the paper "SOME REMARKS ON INDICES OF HOLOMORPHIC VECTOR FIELDS" written by Marco Brunella. I just started it and I'm having some troubles with the introductory concepts. I am currently reading this article named "Local Theory of Holomorphic Foliations and Vector Fields" written by Julio Rebelo and Helena Reis (there's a pdf of it here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.4309v1.pdf .

I would like to know if someone can point me some book or article where the concepts described in the linked file are shown in a more detailed way.

Thanks!